# Failed to fetch packages from jonathonf repository while running Dockerfile from AzureDevOps

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which is getting the packages from a source called jonathonf but it's failing to download some packages from this repository. Could any one please help me with the solution? I have tried very hard to resolve this issue but I am unable to resolve it.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
LABEL maintainer="Praveen"

# Install Python 3.6, Node & Yarn
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl git \
  && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 \
  #These three lines are added to resolve jonathonf issue
  #&& add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
  #&& apt-get update -y \
  #&& apt-get install python3.6 -y \
  #&& apt-get npm \
  #These three lines are added to resolve jonathonf issue
  #&& add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
  && curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
  && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv nodejs --no-install-recommends yarn \
  && apt-get clean \
  && python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade \
  && python3.6 -m pip install wheel

# Install BigARTM
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev python3-setuptools cmake \
  && pip install numpy scipy pandas protobuf==3.0.0 tqdm \
  && git clone --branch=v0.9.0 https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm.git \
  && cd bigartm && mkdir build && cd build \
  && cmake -DPYTHON=python3.6 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. \
  && make && make install
ENV ARTM_SHARED_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libartm.so

# Install Model
WORKDIR /www
COPY application/python_model/requirements.txt ./python_model/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./python_model/requirements.txt \
  && python3.6 -m spacy download en \
  && python3.6 -m nltk.downloader punkt stopwords averaged_perceptron_tagger

# Install NodeJS App
ADD application/package.json application/yarn.lock ./
RUN npm install -g yarn \
  && yarn install \
  && yarn cache clean

ADD application ./

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

**Error:**

```
apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: **Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden**
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y   && apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl git   && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6   && curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -   && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -   && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list   && apt-get update -y   && apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv nodejs --no-install-recommends yarn   && apt-get clean   && python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade   && python3.6 -m pip install wheel' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Error after trying ubuntu:18.04**:

```
Step 10/22 : ADD application/package.json application/yarn.lock ./
 ---> ba08da3d1daa
Step 11/22 : RUN npm install -g yarn   && yarn install   && yarn cache clean
 ---> Running in 72517b8173b6
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/yarn
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/bin/yarn'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/yarn
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-30T10_10_54_161Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g yarn   && yarn install   && yarn cache clean' returned a non-zero code: 239
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g yarn   && yarn install   && yarn cache clean' returned a non-zero code: 239
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 239
```

Comment: Do you specifically need the ubuntu:16.04 image? How about ubuntu:18.04 (bionic)? I think that already includes Python 3.7, so you don't need to install it from the jonathonf ppa.

Comment: I already tried using 18.04 but still we are facing different issues.Please find the error above updated and kindly help me.

Comment: Any update on this please? Someone please help me on the solution as I stuck at this point.

Comment: @GinoMempin I have added my complete docker file.Please see the updated edit and kindly help me to fix this.Please share the docker file so that I will replace with my docker file and run this. Much appreciated if you could help on this fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504515/2745495),
the jonathonf/python3.6 PPA [was removed](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6), and unfortunately that was the "usual"
way of installing Python3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

If the Ubuntu version is not required to be 16.04, you can instead use the Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) image (`ubuntu:bionic` or `ubuntu:18.04`). It already has built-in alternate `apt` sources for installing Python3.6.

```
root@2c4e419e7489:/# apt show python3
Package: python3
Version: 3.6.7-1~18.04
Priority: important
Section: python
Source: python3-defaults
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 191 kB
...
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)

root@2c4e419e7489:/# python3 -V
Python 3.6.9
```

Here is a working Dockerfile that uses `ubuntu:bionic` and installs Python3.6, `node`
and `yarn`. Note that I split it into multiple `RUN` statements just so I can properly
comment out some extra information. You can combine them if you wish. I also don't know
if you have other steps, but your post only mentions those 3.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
LABEL maintainer="Praveen"

# Install essentials
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential software-properties-common curl git

# Install Python 3.6
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Install Node (also installs npm)
#
# Based on official instructions for Ubuntu and Debian
# https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall
#
# The latest is setup_13.x, but I copied your original command that uses setup10.x.
# It might be better to use setup_13.x instead.
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install Yarn
#
# Based on official instructions for Ubuntu and Debian
# https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn
```

Here's the output from the built Docker image:

```
root@34c1457911df:/# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
root@34c1457911df:/# python3 -V
Python 3.6.9
root@34c1457911df:/# python3 -m pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
root@34c1457911df:/# node --version
v10.18.0
root@34c1457911df:/# npm --version
6.13.4
root@34c1457911df:/# yarn --version
1.21.1
```

The posted error message you got when you tried `ubuntu:18.04`

```
Step 11/22 : RUN npm install -g yarn   && yarn install   && yarn cache clean
 ---> Running in 72517b8173b6
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/yarn
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/bin/yarn'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/yarn
```

means that you *already* installed `yarn` (maybe using `apt install yarn`) and then you tried installing it *again* from `npm`. NPM will not overwrite a previous installation unless you [`--force`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)
it to. But, since you already installed it from `apt`, you don't need to install it again with `npm`. (I don't use `yarn` though, so I don't know if there's a difference with `yarn` from `apt` or from `npm`.)

Answer (score 0):

Let me walk you through how a problem like this can be debugged on your own:

- You see an error message when building the `dockerfile` that indicates a 403 Forbidden error.
- That error is giving you a clear source of the problem: The package repository. If you try to open the URL in a browser, you see that you're still getting a 403 error. Yes, it's definitely a problem with the package repository.
- Visiting the package maintainer's root page gives you more detail on the source of the problem: Your `dockerfile` is invalid because the author of those packages has purposefully unpublished them.

> This PPA has been removed from public access as part of a protest against the abuse of open-source projects by large companies. For more detail visit the main page here: [https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf)
>
> If you are a company and you would like this PPA to continue then let me know your preferred route for contributions and I will arrange something.
>
> If we have already been in contact then ping me your Launchpad ID and I will add you to a private PPA in the meantime.

[Ref](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6)

So the solution to your problem is to find an alternate source for the packages or to contact the author of the package.

Comment: I need a alternate solution. I have tried and looked at the things already which you explained .So that's why I have asked for the solution and only we need to purchase PPA or we need to find a different way.I have even tried to use different packages but none of them gave me the result.All other repos not useful for my dockerfile.So kindly provide the alternate PPA Repo which can be replaced with Jonathonf PPA.So that I am good to proceed on this.Much appreciated if you could help me on this please.